# Peculiar error in perl Program

Tags: perl, working-directory

I have written this perl program to copy certain type of files . I see very annoying and peculiar error when I run this program.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;


for (my $LAMBDA=0; $LAMBDA<1.05;$LAMBDA += 0.05) {
    print "Processing configuration $LAMBDA...\n";
    chdir "Lambda_${LAMBDA}/Production_MD";
    system("cp *.tpr   ../../dimer_tprs ");
    chdir "../..";
}
```

I see this error.

```
Processing configuration 0...

Processing configuration 0.05...

Processing configuration 0.1...

Processing configuration 0.15...

Processing configuration 0.2...

cp: cannot stat `*.tpr': No such file or directory
Processing configuration 0.25...
cp: cannot stat `*.tpr': No such file or directory
Processing configuration 0.3...
cp: cannot stat `*.tpr': No such file or directory
Processing configuration 0.35...
cp: cannot stat `*.tpr': No such file or directory
Processing configuration 0.4...
cp: cannot stat `*.tpr': No such file or directory
Processing configuration 0.45...
cp: cannot stat `*.tpr': No such file or directory
Processing configuration 0.5...
cp: cannot stat `*.tpr': No such file or directory
Processing configuration 0.55...
cp: cannot stat `*.tpr': No such file or directory
Processing configuration 0.6...
cp: cannot stat `*.tpr': No such file or directory
Processing configuration 0.65...
cp: cannot stat `*.tpr': No such file or directory
Processing configuration 0.7...
cp: cannot stat `*.tpr': No such file or directory
Processing configuration 0.75...
cp: cannot stat `*.tpr': No such file or directory
Processing configuration 0.8...
cp: cannot stat `*.tpr': No such file or directory
Processing configuration 0.85...
cp: cannot stat `*.tpr': No such file or directory
Processing configuration 0.9...
cp: cannot stat `*.tpr': No such file or directory
Processing configuration 0.95...
cp: cannot stat `*.tpr': No such file or directory
Processing configuration 1...
cp: cannot stat `*.tpr': No such file or directory
```

---

so it copies first 2-3 then it's says no such file or directory but but the files are there as well as directory. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues I see. The first is floating point math. Floating point math always has some error, although in this case It does not look to be significant. The other is that you are not doing error checking on your `chdir`s. I think Lambda_0.2/Production_MD is missing, which will confuse everything from there as you see. This may be an easier solution:

```
find . -maxdepth 3 -mindepth 3 -path "Lambda_*/Production_MD/*.tpr" -print0 |\
grep --null-data -e "Lambda_0\.[0-9]5\?/Production_MD/*.tpr" -e "Lambda_1\.0/Production_MD/*.tpr"|\
xargs -0r cp -t dimer_tprs
```

Comment: 3rd issue: if any of those directories are symlinks, the `chdir(../..)` will not necessarily take you back to where you were.

Comment: True, and I may have missed others. I just quit looking.

Comment: Hi , Friends sorry for the time waste . My Lambda_0.15 was missing that's why I was getting that error ..Thanks for the help.

Comment: @VikasDubey if you had error checking on your `chdir`s it would have caught that.